# Regex in JavaScript to validate both decimal and numerical values

Tags: regex, extjs, decimal, numerical

I am working with `EXT-JS` and am using a `VType` to specify the `regex` for a particular field in a form.

I need this field to accept values like:
`1, 11, 11561.464, 1.0, 56.0,` etc and reject values like:

`.1, 1., 56.`(I need my values to start and end with a digit)

I have used the following regular expressions:

1. `/^([0-9][0-9]*)([.])?([0-9]*[0-9])$/`
       This accepts values like 21.,.1 2.2 and rejects values like  1., 2.,1.0
2. `/^\d+(\.\d)?/`
       This accepts values like 1.,11.
3. `/^\d+\.?(\d+)$/`
       This accepts values like  11., 1.1,11.1 and rejects values like 1.

Why is it the same regular regex rejects values like 1.(Single digit + a decimal, which is acceptable) but accepts values like 11.(double digit + a decimal, which is totally unacceptable)

Comment: The last regex works for me. Please post some code.

Comment: @Doorknob the last pattern cannot accept single digit numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second pattern is pretty much all the way there. One thing: you forgot the string-end anchor:

```
/^\d+(\.\d)?$/
```

Now there can be no trailing periods.

Another thing: you should repeat the second `\d+` as well, unless you want to limit yourself to one decimal place:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Finally, it's generally good practice to suppress capturing unless you explicitly need it:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for both

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the dot ;)